# Why do I get many repeated compiling messages during a grails build in intelliJ

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

Here's the build console trace when I launch a grails 2.0 app in intellij in debug mode.  It didn't used to be so verbose in grails 1.3.4

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\java" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:57461,suspend=y,server=n -Dgrails.home=C:\grails-2.0.0.M2 -Dbase.dir=C:\apps\myapp "-Dtools.jar=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\lib\tools.jar" -Dgroovy.starter.conf=C:\grails-2.0.0.M2/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Xmx1G -Xms356m -XX:MaxPermSize=356m -javaagent:C:\Users\aressler\.IntelliJIdea10\system\groovyHotSwap\gragent.jar -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\grails-2.0.0.M2\lib\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars\groovy-all-1.8.2.jar;C:\grails-2.0.0.M2\dist\grails-bootstrap-2.0.0.M2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf C:\grails-2.0.0.M2/conf/groovy-starter.conf "-Dserver.port=80 run-app"
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57461', transport: 'socket'

| Loading Grails 2.0.0.M2
| Configuring classpath
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development
| Environment set to development.
| Environment set to development..
| Environment set to development...
| Environment set to development....
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application
| Packaging Grails application.
| Packaging Grails application..
| Compiling 3 source files
| Compiling 3 source files.
| Compiling 3 source files..
| Compiling 1 source files
| Compiling 1 source files.
| Compiling 1 source files..
| Compiling 1 source files...
| Compiling 1 source files....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Running Grails application
```

This is on a build where I had made no changes from the last restart.  Am I wasting lots of time on each restart with it doing wasted extra packaging and compiling?

Comment: I should have added that I cannot tell if these messages are repeated when running grails run-app from the command line.  The new model where it overwrites the messages obscures what is happening.  BTW, that isn't a great feature.

Answer (score 3):

Grails 2 is not doing any more work. The reason for the repeated lines is that the new Grails 2 console is telling you that it is still working and progress is being made by adding a new period at the end of the current message.

When working in IntelliJ with Grails 2 I use `--verbose` and `--plain-output` to get legacy style logging. The Grails 2 console uses JLine for a more rich command line experience but the IntelliJ console isn't exactly comparable. I throw on `--stacktrace` for good measure as well when using IntelliJ.

Comment: Yes, but what is causing the repeated messages?  Is it wrong and actually recompiling the same 3 files 3 times?

Comment: Nope. It's just indicating progress. Its just compiling 3 files then 1. Notice the periods after each subsequent line. You can view the source code for all of this here https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-bootstrap/src/main/groovy/grails/build/logging/GrailsConsole.java

Comment: JLine also breaks the terminal (until a `reset` is issued) on Linux if the JVM doesn't exit cleanly

Answer (score 0):

I've created [request in IntelliJ tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-123140) to make `-plain-output` option by default.

Comment: In the Intellij 13.1 EAP ([build 135.667](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+13.1+135.667+Release+Notes)) this issue has been fixed.